# How to read a text file content and write to another text file after formatting the text file content using Java?

Tags: java, string, substring

Need help to write a text file content after modifying or formatting from another source text file using Java. Let's say I have below the text content in the source text file(text1.txt). I have searched stack over flow for any possible duplicate but I could not able to find. All existing stack over flow questions were related to how to read and write text/file only.

> ********Total_Load_Start The total load applied(Users)     : 8Total_Load_End
>   *****************Avg_Start The Avg Response time(ms) for 8 requests : 2837 msAvg_End ******************Success_start The Success % for load
>   of 8 requests  : 100.0 %Success_end ******************CPUPeak_Start
>   The Cpu peak % usage during the load of 8 requests      :1
>   %CPUPeak_End ****************** Pass_StartThe total succesful
>   responses during the load of 8 requests      :8
>   Pass_End******************Fail_Start The total failed responses during
>   the load of 8 requests      :0 %Fail_End *********

Now I required to read and write to destination or output text file text2.txt in below the format:

```
Total_Load_Start The total load applied(Users)     : 8 

Avg_Start The Avg Response time(ms) for 8 requests : 2837 ms

Success_start The Success % for load of 8 requests  : 100.0 % 

CPUPeak_Start The Cpu peak % usage during the load of 8 requests      :1 %

Pass_StartThe total succesful responses during the load of 8 requests      :8 

Fail_Start The total failed responses during the load of 8 requests      :0 %
```

Any help would be appreciated.

I have tried like this:

```
    static void modifyFile(String filePath, String oldString, String newString){
       File fileToBeModified = new File(filePath);
       String oldContent = "*";
       BufferedReader reader = null;
       FileWriter writer = null;

    try{
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileToBeModified));
        String line = reader.readLine();
        String [] separado = line.split("\\*");

        while (separado != null) {
            oldContent = oldContent + line + System.lineSeparator();
            line = reader.readLine();
        }

        String newContent = oldContent.replaceAll(oldString, newString);
        writer = new FileWriter(fileToBeModified);
        writer.write(newContent);
        reader.close();
        writer.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    TextFileReadWrite.modifyFile("C:\\Users\\raman\\Documents\\TestLoad_Final_Result.txt", "*", "");
    System.out.println("done");
}
```

Comment: while writing you can skip '*' character . for actual code find from [here](http://www.codejava.net/java-se/file-io/how-to-read-and-write-text-file-in-java)

Comment: replace "******************" with new line "\n" something like this

Comment: @vincrichaud added the code snippet, you are so hurry to down vote?

Comment: @Raman Thanks for adding it (for info I didn't downvote). You have a problem in your while-loop you will never exit since `seprarado` is not null and never changed inside the loop.

Comment: `Total_Load_Start The total load applied(Users) : 8Total_Load_End 
Avg_Start The Avg Response time(ms) for 8 requests : 2837 msAvg_End 
Success_start The Success % for load of 8 requests : 100.0 %Success_end 
CPUPeak_Start The Cpu peak % usage during the load of 8 requests :1 %CPUPeak_End 
 Pass_StartThe total succesful responses during the load of 8 requests :8 Pass_End
Fail_Start The total failed responses during the load of 8 requests :0 %Fail_End` is this the output you want ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Path originalPath = Paths.get("file1.txt");
    //Read the file content and add each line in list
    List<String> orginalContentLines = Files.readAllLines(originalPath);

    //Combine all lines to one string
    String originalContent = orginalContentLines.stream().collect(Collectors.joining("\r\n"));

    //Format the content by replacing * with new line
    String newContent = originalContent.replaceAll("\\*+", "\r\n");

    //Create the new file 
    Path newPath = Paths.get("file2.txt");
    Files.createFile(newPath);

    //Write to new file
    Files.write(newPath, newContent.getBytes());
```

Comment: this is giving `Total_Load_Start The total load applied(Users) : 8Total_Load_End 
Avg_Start The Avg Response time(ms) for 8 requests : 2837 msAvg_End 
Success_start The Success % for load of 8 requests : 100.0 %Success_end 
CPUPeak_Start The Cpu peak % usage during the load of 8 requests :1 %CPUPeak_End 
 Pass_StartThe total succesful responses during the load of 8 requests :8 Pass_End
Fail_Start The total failed responses during the load of 8 requests :0 %Fail_End` is that op wants?